# Why is this one in-topic and this one isn't, when they are the same question?

Tags: discussion

[Is there any way to rehabilitate the "junk rare" Lost In The Woods?](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/6195/is-there-any-way-to-rehabilitate-the-junk-rare-lost-in-the-woods)

[Has there ever been any use for Lich?](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/23169/has-there-ever-been-any-use-for-lich/23172)

Same question, different card.

One has been appreciated by the community, while with the other one I'm being mocked.

I'm refraining from throwing insults AOE, since I know this wouldn't help, but I definitely feel insulted.

Comment: One thing to remember is that the rules for acceptable questions do change over time and the other question you linked was asked over 3 years ago.

Comment: I actually think the question is fine, and I wouldn't vote to close it. I suspect that at least some of the problem people have is with your tone. The last paragraph especially (I know it was added in an edit) reads as somewhat condescending and seems to imply that readers wouldn't normally "pay attention."

Answer (score 4):

This sort of question is often referred to as a [broken window](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/broken-windows/info). It gets asked so often that main meta has a tag for it. There are many reasonable explanations for why your question received different treatment.

- The question is three years old. The community three years ago may have been more lax when it comes to opinionated questions.
- Close vote reasons are subjective.
- Different users see different questions.

I see no evidence that the community was mocking you. There's normally some negativity present when close voting happens, because nobody likes their question to be closed. If you firmly believe that another user is mocking or insulting you, flag the comment.